# visual studio 2015 find and replace not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, find-replace

After Windows 10 auto installed the Anniversary Update, along with installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (using Visual Studio Enterprise Edition), any time I try to use the Find in Files, or Replace in Files window has a scrambled UI, and no am unable to click / use any of the controls.

I have attached screen shots of the Find in Files, Replace in Files for reference purposes.

Any ideas on how to fix it. Never realized how much I depended on the Find in Files tool until it's been taken away from me!

[image: Find in File UI]

[image: Replace in Files UI]

Comment: i'd start with reinstalling visual studio if that failed, and it most likely will, i'd put the blame on the net framework. try removing prior versions and installing the latest version instead. fixing the current net framework version never worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to have fixed itself with the Oct 12 windows update. From looking at the descriptions of the 'Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1607 for x64-based Systems ([KB3194798](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3194798))'. Unable to duplicate this issue anymore